# taking two values from an array and passing them as variables to a function

Tags: php

How can I pass specifically the number of 2 values from an array into a function then loop over the array and take the next 2 values from the array.

For example

```
<?php
    $fileArray Array("file1", "file2", "file3", "file4", "file5", "file6", "file7", "file8", "file9", "file10")

    function fileFunction($file1, $file2)
    {
     $dostuffhere;
    }

    [loop]
    fileFunction($fileArray[$key], $fileArray[$key]);
    [/loop]
?>
```

*Note* that the `$fileArray` can and will be longer than 10 items.

Comment: ANd what about the odd number of elements ?

Comment: Is there a reason youre not just passing the array to the function?

Comment: @UserB - check my comment in answer, hopefully that clarifies more.

Comment: @Galen - I'd still have a problem of only using 2 values in the function whether I passed the array first to the function or not. Unless you were thinking of something (if so, love to read your answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_chunk() sounds like it's the function you want if you are always going to have an even number of records or your function can work with just one parameter (please confirm this)

```
if(isset($fileArray) and is_array($fileArray) and $fileChunk = array_chunk($fileArray,2) and is_array($fileChunk))
{
  foreach($fileChunk as $value)
  {
    fileFunction($value[0],$value[1]);
  }
}
```

the array_chunk() function will split an array into indexed sub-arrays in collections of N

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: there will always only be 2 values passed as the nature of the function (to compare 2 files side by side). Thanks, thats exactly what I needed.